# Unexpected behavior between String.IsNullOrEmpty and DBNull.Value

Tags: c#

I have the following query:

```
public static string GetCustomerName(string customerNo)
{
   string query = "query to get customer";
   var myConn= new MYConnection();
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConn.MYConnectionString))
   {
       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = customerNo;
       object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
       return result == DBNull.Value ? String.Empty : (string)result;
   }

}
```

I'm calling the method above like this:

```
string customerName = GetCustomerName(CustomerID);

if (customerName.Contains(Constants.Company.CompanyName))
{

    Additional Logic...
}
```

However, I'm getting a Object Reference Null error if my method doesn't return a customer name. I would think that the GetCustomer method would return an empty string.

If I change the call to get the CustomerName to below, it works perfectly.

```
string customerName = GetCustomerName(emailAndSTCodeInfo.CustomerID);
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName))
{
    customerName = "";
}
if (customerName.Contains(Constants.Chase.ACCOUNT_NAME))
{
    Additional Logic
}
```

So, my question is, what would be the proper way of handling this if my GetCustomer method doesn't find a record and returns null. I'm currently using the working code above but it seems like a hack or something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you debug, what _is_ the value of `result` prior to your return statement?

Comment: Please make more effort when formatting your question. There's no need to have the code starting a third of the way across the window.

Comment: Do you ever expect `GetCustomerName()` to return null? If not and if your logic depends on `CustomerName`, then I'd say throwing exception and catching it on the upper layer (caller method) would be the best way to handle this.

Comment: this may sound funny, but I can't actually 'debug' this. It's a windows service that is very large. For some reason, corporate has some odd email setup that blocks this program from sending emails from my development machine. I know, it makes it a nightmare. It's suppose to be fixed soon...Not soon enough though.

Comment: You can still write tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` returns null if no record is returned.

To guarantee that `GetCustomerName` never returns null, you could change the last line to

```
return Convert.ToString(result);
```

`Convert.ToString(object)` returns an empty string if the argument is either null or `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 2):

If a query returns no rows, then executing it with `ExecuteScalar` will return `null`, not `DBNull.Value`.

So your `GetCustomerName` method needs to check for a `null` return value as well as `DBNull.Value`.